# Drupal - change prev/next button text in pager

Tags: button, text, drupal-7, overriding, pager

Somehow I can't change the text on the Next button in a view. I tried to do it with the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module, but that only worked for the Previous button. I made sure that I copied the text that was on the Next button and replaced that but it didn't work.

I tried to change the label of the button in the includes/pager.inc file but that didn't work either.

So now I'm asking you guys, what should I do?

Thanks in advance,
Alexandberg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I must have failed when I first tried to replace it with String Overrides because I tried again and believe it or not, it worked.

I'm not sure what the solution was, but I'd guess I forgot to clear the cache (which I usually don't need to when overriding strings), or maybe I copied the text wrong.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hack Drupal core files like includes/pager.inc just because you need one different label on your site! What theme are you using? If changing next button label in pager.inc didn't help, it's possible your theme overrides it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the **[JS Injector](http://drupal.org/project/js_injector)** module and write use the `Document.getElementById('ID_Of_The_Text').innerHtml="Tect_You_Want" ;`